# Why is ExifInterfac returning 0 for latitude and longitude values?

Tags: android, kotlin, exif

This is the code I am using. It correctly identities the images that should have lat/longs but it does not give the correct value, simply returning 0 for both.

```
 val latLong = FloatArray(2)
            val hasLatLong = exif?.getLatLong(latLong)
            if (hasLatLong == true) {
                println(latLong[0])
                println(latLong[1])
            }
```

Why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: @blackapps I am

Comment: which would be?

Comment: Have you validated that the data is actually non-zero? Use a program like `exiftool` to do so. You might also try my Java library for extracting data from images, such as GPS: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor